# Home screen does not appear after creating Virtual Host in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, virtualhost

I install *Drupal 7.56* in my PC with **MAMP**. 
 After installation complete, drupal admin screen appears.

[image]

Then, I create **virtual host named "cast.dev"**. 
When I type "cast.dev" in browser, it does not show anything and only shows "It works !".

[image]

I also create a front page. It does not show also. 
 Could anyone tell me which part am I need to do more? Thanks .

Comment: Here its showing the localhost page. How do you configured virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the follwing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myproject.local
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /home/user/path/to/myproject_folder
  <Directory /home/user/path/to/myproject_folder>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart your Apache using the following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Set up localhost file by adding the following code on  the 'hosts' file from 'etc'.

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.local
```

For this,edit hosts using gedit with the following command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```